# How to build an integration with rest API in apex using XML

Tags: rest, xml, dom

**Situation**

I need to build a connection from Salesforce to "post" to a rest api.  The recipient has given me XDS schema files of the data to be sent over.

**My Current Plan**

1. Build a sObject to be the object to send.
2. Match the sObjects fields to the schema defined in the xds file.
3. Write the XML using the [DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_xml_dom.htm)
4. Post the XML

I feel like this method is kinda laborious **is there a better way?**

Comment: You don't need a `SObject` for this. As long as you know what parameters you need to post, and from where your data will be sourced for those parameters, you just need to build the request body, and post it to the endpoint.

Comment: My reasoning with the sObject is that some of our data needs to be in certain formats before sending. So my thoughts where to use the Sobject as a staging ground to normalize the data in config

Comment: I would still recommend not to have one. You can easily do the *transformation* right in your apex class. If you introduce a `SObject`, you are introducing some overhead as well. You will need to make lots of considerations e.g., you will additionally need to take care of removing data from it as it counts towards your storage. Who should have visibility to that object, etc. etc.

Comment: yeah that makes sense! thank you for your input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When XML is bit tricky, then I just design it myself using String manipulation.

```
String myXML = '<Body> +
                        '<Name>' + account.Name + '</Name>' +
                        '<Age>' + account.Age + '</Age>' +
                        '<Id>' + account.Id + '</Id>' +
                        '<DOB>' + account.DOB + '</DOB>' +
                '</Body>';
```

This makes code readable as well.

Comment: as apposed to doing something like this https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/102090/best-practices-for-generating-large-xml-files ?

Comment: I am Definitely considering your solution in comparison haha I have 30 fields to do this for.

Comment: Yups both are creating XML, this way is faster, readable, simpler. I can't think of a reason to not use this. If someone disagrees i would like to know why.

Comment: Sounds good haha thanks again